# Why does session cookie only show '.com' for the DOMAIN when viewed in IE8?

Tags: .net, cookies, internet-explorer-8

I am using the following code to set a session cookie

```
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("visitId");
        cookie.Value = value;
        cookie.Domain = ".example.com";

        Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
```

This works fine, although I was surprised to see in IE8 when I hit F12 (developer tools) and then 'Cache > View Cookie Information' I get the following. It says '.com' instead of 'example.com'

```
NAME  visitId 
VALUE  1472215 
DOMAIN  .com 
PATH  / 
EXPIRES  At the end of the Session
```

The HTTP header sent says this :

```
Set-Cookie: visitId=1472215; domain=.example.com; path=/
```

Whats going on? Why is IE8 showing only .com for the domain? Is this just the way session cookies work. That doesnt make sense of course.

What was interesting to me is that a persistent cookie shows this, when set using the same code.

```
NAME  userGUID 
VALUE  e1cbe4f3-6300-44e1-a702-b449d5711816 
DOMAIN  example.com 
PATH  / 
EXPIRES  3/27/2010 1:05:14 AM
```

Am I misunderstanding something or is this just a bug in their 'cookie' display logic?

I've verified at least that it isn't sending the cookies to stackoverflow.com :-)

Comment: i just checked bank of america's online banking -- it gives the same behavior! if i go F12, 'Cache > Clear Session Cookie' it will clear the session cookies

Comment: I'm grappling with what seems to be the same issue now on IE10.  I set the cookie on a subdomain e.g. test.mydomain.co.nz, and Developer tools insists the cookie is for mydomain.co.nz.  This is annoying because I don't particularly want this cookie to be sent to live.mydomain.co.nz but IE suggests it will!

Answer (score 0):

If the cookie send with the HTTP header is correct, then it looks like a developer tools bug?!

Comment: thats what i was wondering. I've tried with or without the period at the beginning of the domain name. I was never clear what the difference was though.

Comment: what i find strange though is the developer tool is just showing me an xslt transformation for an XML file : C:\Users\SWEAVER\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Low\Content.IE5\Coo7E87.xml  (yes it does say IE5 !!!)

Comment: A cookie with a domain starting with a period is valid for that domain and any subdomains, whereas without a period it's just valid for that domain. I would imagine this is just a developer tools bug too though.